# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{m}kn^k)x^n$ $m\in \mathbb{N}$ Some constant

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

How can I prove or disprove uniform convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{m}kn^k)x^n$ $m\in \mathbb{N}$  Some constant

Comment: Trying to use the d'Alembert and also use Stolz–Cesàro theorem but do not understand how I can?

Comment: Assuming $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant as well, $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{k=0}^m kn^k)x^n = 0$ is necessary for convergence of the infinite series. For $x \geq 1$ this necessary condition does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^mkn^k $ can be evaluated explicitly, but it suffices to estimate it as follows
$$ m\,n^m\le a_n\le m^2\, n^m$$ The radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ is equal $1.$ The series is not convergent at $x=\pm 1.$ Thus uniform convergence holds for $|x|\le r$  and any fixed $r<1.$

Comment: How did you calculate The radius of convergence of the series? Cauchy – Hadamard theorem or D’Alembert?

Comment: You can use Cauchy formula: take $n$th root  of three sides of the inequality. You will obtain $a_n^{1/n}\to 1$ by the squeeze principle.

Comment: Why you use $a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^mkn^k $ and not $a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^mkn^k $?